# How to find intel hd graphics panel Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: intel-graphics

10 there is a settings panel for intel hd graphics. It was pre installed in both OS. I think Ubuntu 20.04(focal fossa) also has the drivers installed but i want to configure it.

Please find me the solution for finding the graphics settings panel.
I have got only intel hd 510 graphics and no nvidia graphics card.

Comment: I don't know of any specific settings panel for intel graphics. What is it you need to configure?

Comment: I want to tweak the contrast and brightness of monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Drivers are mostly included and in some case can be installed.
but graphic panel for ubuntu is not developed by intel for linux
[SEE THIS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000055711/graphics.html) There is no any instruction to install the same for linux.

More over there may be any such app for ubuntu by some developer but that may work or not.

some driver information for linux is officially provided [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005520/graphics.html).